# Asp.net web api 2 datetime input parameters change localisation

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I send a request from javascript to web api controller for example, ../api/person/updateBirthDate?id=1&birthDate=dd/MM/yyyy 
I'm not sending json format so please don't say use Json serilizer. I just use post an url with parameters like form submit. How can I solve this issue at server side in order to get the date formatted as dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the splash `/` is not allowed in the URL parameters. Use `%2F` instead. So the URL:

> ../api/person/updateBirthDate?id=1&birthDate=01/01/2000

should be sent as:

> ../api/person/updateBirthDate?id=1&birthDate=01%2F01%2F2000

Now, on your server, all the URL parameters will arrive as `string`, so you need to parse them like this:

```
int Id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
DateTime BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["birthDate"]);
```